# Display Advanced settings window for COM port in C#

Tags: c#, winapi, serial-port, device-manager

I have written in C# a simple application to list all COM ports in PC. It saves me a lot of time since I work with multiple USB to serial converters. I would like to have a fast access to changing COM port number for selected adapter.

I display them in ListBox. I would like to open Property page or Advanced settings window when right clicking on an item (like Device Manager does in popup menu Properties).

For listing devices I use:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE Name LIKE \"%(COM%\"");
```

I found that in WINAPI there exists fuction *[SerialDisplayAdvancedSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547447%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)* but I have no idea how to access it in C# and how to provide its parameters.

Is there a way how to display system Property dialog for selected COM port device?

Comment: Wrong way around.  It is the device driver author that uses this function to display his custom property page.  He needs to do this in his property page provider, a "plugin" that Device Manager uses.  Not everything that DM does is exposed in an api.

Answer (score 0):

You can use P/Invoke to call the WINAPI function from your C# code. pinvoke.net has examples although not specifically for the function in which you are interested. But there's enough info there to help you.